# IncrementalListView not appearing xamarin forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, itemtemplate

I'm building an app with Xamarin forms and i wanted to use the [IncrementalListView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IncrementalListView.FormsPlugin/)

I've seen these 2 implementations [1](https://github.com/therealjohn/IncrementalListView) and [2](https://jmillerdev.net/incremental-listview-control-and-plugin-for-xamarin-forms/) but none seems to work properly so i mixed both to be able to run my code.

The problem now is that nothing is being displayed on the View.

Here is my code:

**ImovsPage.cs**

```
public partial class ImovsPage : ContentPage
{

    public Task Initialization { get; private set; }
    public static LinkedList<Imovel> Imoveis { get; set; }

    public ImovsPage()
    {
        Initialization = InitializeAsync();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        Imoveis = await Imovel.GetInitializedListAsync();
    }
}
```

**ImovsPage.cs.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:plugin="clr-namespace:IncrementalListView.FormsPlugin;assembly=IncrementalListView.FormsPlugin"
    x:Class="YmoApp.ImovsPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <plugin:IncrementalListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Imoveis}"
            PreloadCount="5">

            <x:Arguments>
                <ListViewCachingStrategy>RecycleElement</ListViewCachingStrategy>
            </x:Arguments>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Imagens}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Valor}"/>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <ActivityIndicator Margin="20" IsRunning="{Binding IsLoadingIncrementally}" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoadingIncrementally}"/>        
            </ListView.Footer>
        </plugin:IncrementalListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**View Model**

```
public class IncrementalViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, ISupportIncrementalLoading
    {
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = Settings.MaxImoveis;

        public ICommand LoadMoreItemsCommand { get; set; }

        public bool IsLoadingIncrementally { get; set; }

        public bool HasMoreItems { get; set; }

        public IncrementalViewModel()
        {
            LoadMoreItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await LoadMoreItems());
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        async Task LoadMoreItems()
        {
            IsLoadingIncrementally = true;

            Settings.incrementPage();
            // Download data from a service, etc.
            // Add the newly download data to a collection
            foreach(Imovel imovel in await Imovel.GetInitializedListAsync()){
                ImovsPage.Imoveis.AddLast(imovel);

            }

            HasMoreItems = (ImovListRequest.Total < Settings.Page * Settings.MaxImoveis);

            IsLoadingIncrementally = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered on the [github issue](https://github.com/therealjohn/IncrementalListView/issues/4)